# Use of super () in python

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, superclass

When I execute the following:

```
class animal(object):
      def desc(self):
             print 'animal'
class human():
      def desc(self):
              print 'human'
class satyr(human, animal):
      def desc(self):
              print 'satyr'

grover=satyr()
super(satyr, grover).desc()
```

I get human! 
But human did not even inherit the class object, and I think super works only if class object is inherited. (New style class)

Now if I make animal also not inherit class object, I get an error. 
What is going on here?

Comment: please format your code

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance

Comment: @Brendan, no it is not. I read that already. That one asks about the left to right approach of python.

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup your edit specifically removed the issue the OP was asking about. Please don't do that.

Comment: I do not want human to inherit from object. Please don't edit my code to change that. That is the point of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works that way because only one of the classes or inherited classes needs to inherit from `object` in order for your class to be created by the metaclass that `object` uses.  The metaclass controls this MRO behavior.

Here is [one of the better answers on stack overflow explaining metaclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/1547004).

In python 3, this is all moot, since everything is a new-style class.  Also, there's really no reason **NOT** to inherit from `object`, so unless you're forced to use some old library with classes that don't inherit from `object`, you might as well have all your classes inherit from it.

Comment: Thank you. That helped a lot.